# Order of execution for Tests in TestNg, If Priority set only for few Test Methods

Tags: automated-testing, testng, test-strategy

I have three methods as mentioned below, two with priority ( 0 , 1 ) and third method(Test) with no priority attribute.

What is the order of execution.

Code snippet given below.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    private void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test Priority One- Revision");
    }
    @Test(priority = 0)
    private void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test Priority Zero - Revision");
    }
    @Test
    private void ztestNP() {
        System.out.println("Test NoPriority- Revision");
    }
```

What is the expected Order?

I expected

```
Test Priority Zero - Revision Test 
Priority One- Revision Test 
NoPriority- Revision
```

But Getting

```
Test Priority Zero - Revision
Test NoPriority- Revision 
Test Priority One- Revision
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you have to consider 2 points :

1. If you are not using any priority in your test method then TestNG assign by default `priority=0` to the Test Method
2. If there is same priority assign to test methods then execution order will be alphabetically.

So in your case it is adding `priority=0` internally to your `ztestNP()` methods

```
@Test(priority=0)
public void ztestNP() {
    System.out.println("Test NoPriority- Revision");
}
```

So your output what you are getting is correct.

Now if you want to test execution order of same priority methods(*will execute in alphabetical order*)

e.g.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void btest1() {
    System.out.println("Test Priority One- Revision");
}
@Test(priority = 1)
public void atest2() {
    System.out.println("Test Priority Zero - Revision");
}
@Test(priority = 0)
public void ztestNP() {
    System.out.println("Test NoPriority- Revision");
}
```

Then output will be :

> Test NoPriority- Revision
>
> Test Priority Zero - Revision
>
> Test Priority One- Revision

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set priority by default, the method will have a priority of zero. When you have multiple methods with the same priority they will be run in alphabetical order.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what it adds to the existing, accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well Better Way to execute TestNG Class With XML Suite This will Run Your TestNG class methods As per Mentioned In XML

```
<test name = "Test1">  <!-- Give Specific Package and className -->
    <classes>
        <class name = "Actual_TestNG_Class_Name">  <!-- Give Specific Package and className -->
            <methods>
                <include name = "MethodName1"/> 
                <include name = "MethodName2"/> 
                <include name = "MethodName3"/> 
            </methods>

         </class>
    </classes>      

</test>
```